# What is the best way to filter user input with a blacklist in Grails?

Tags: grails, filter, grails-2.0, blacklist

On my website I allow users to create user profiles where they can choose a username.

```
class User {

   String username
}
```

What is the best way to filter and restrict forbidden words like porn or so from a blacklist?
Is there a best practice how to do that? Is there a Grails plugin that handles the filtering?
At which layer should I do the filtering Controller, Domain Model, ...?

Comment: I imagine you could map a restrictedWords table with a list (that you populated) to compare the Username to at time of creation, and reject it if there's a match.

Answer (score 1):

There are various ways to achieve this. If you have a list of blacklisted /restricted/forbidden words you can either:

1. Trigger an XHR call to check `username` in blacklist on tab out from `username` field.
2. Else, Create a taglib and check whether `username` is not in blacklist.
3. Else, create a filter over the controller to filter out blacklisted username and redirect user to error page.
4. Else, Validate `username` inside Command Object before binding it to domain class.
5. Else, validate `username` in `beforeInsert` and `beforeUpdate` events of domain class.

Out of all those approaches #1 is preemptive and effective because of an AJAX request making an optimistic check before page submit and page reload. The least preferred would be #5.